# WPF special centring of a text

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I have a function which format the text in order to have a centered text surrounded by further text. Basically the input string is:

*Quit{C}OK{C}Quit*

and the result should be:

`Quit      OK      Quit`

Here's the code:

```
    public string CenterText(string mess)
    {
        string[] token = new string[] {"{L}", "{C}", "{R}" };    // #PL#: padding left, #PC#: padding center, #PR#: padding right            
        if (!token.Any(mess.Contains))
            return mess;
        if (mess.Contains("{C}"))
        {
            Int32 messLenghtWithoutToken = mess.Replace("{C}", string.Empty).Length;
            Int32 emptySpaces = this.display_x - messLenghtWithoutToken;    // this.display_x = 22
            Int32 tokenOccurence = Regex.Matches(mess, "{C}").Count;
            Int32 spacesPerToken = emptySpaces / tokenOccurence;

            return mess.Replace("{C}", new String(' ', spacesPerToken));
        }
    }
```

The problem is that I cannot calculate exactly how much space (in pixel) require the emty space (chr 32). Infact the result changes based on the length of each words I want to show. How can I calculate exactly how much spaces I need to put among my words?

My text is displayed into a TextBlock control

Comment: I don't think so @Hostel

Comment: Sorry, I put this in wrong post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace the textblock with a grid with three cells that each have a text block. Set the width of the center column to Auto and the width of the outer columns to *

Set the horizontal text alignment of the left textblock to Right and of the right one to Left and set margins to specify the spacing.

```
<Grid>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="auto"/>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <TextBlock Grid.Column="0" TextAlignment="Right" Margin="0,0,5,0" Text="LEFT"/>
    <TextBlock Grid.Column="1" TextAlignment="Center" Margin="5,0,5,0" Text="CENTER"/>
    <TextBlock Grid.Column="2" TextAlignment="Left" Margin="5,0,0,0" Text="RIGHT"/>
</Grid>
```

That should do pixel perfect alignment for you.

Your proposed solution will not work because the calculation of the character width depends on the font and as you indicated, on the number of characters.